# module.exports wont work in node.js (no errors present)

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I remember module.exports working perfectly fine once before but today It would'nt res.send. I simply receive a blank page with no errors. Could you explain why? I am quite confused. Here is an image of my directory structure if for some reason you need it: [HERE!](http://s29.postimg.org/3sz3l43dz/upload.png)

Code(Important parts)
As you can see, I am attempting to get the `test` variable in with the `index.js` file. I required the file and put it out as an export.

App.js

```
var express  = require('express');
var http     = require('http');
var path     = require('path');

var app      = module.exports       = express();

// all environments go here...

require('./routes/index.js');

//create server here
```

routes/index.js

```
var app = require('../app.js');

app.get('/testing', function(req,res) {
    var logic = require('./logic.js');
    res.send(logic.test);
});

//other routes below
```

routes/logic.js

```
var test = module.exports = "Hello World";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `module.exports` in a wrong way to achieve your result. Try:

```
module.exports.test = "Hello world";
```

`test` should be a property of `module.exports` object if you want to use `module.test` afterwards

Comment: `exports.test` would be preferred in this case I think

Comment: @monkeyinsight That is an error. You are creating a variable called module.exports.test, you are making no sense....

Comment: p.s. I fixed my issue. It should be: `module.exports.test = test;` I also don't know why my method is incorrect, It's worked before. For example in the app.js file

Comment: @nousernamesremained yeah... late night, making mistakes. in your `app.js` you are using only 1 variable that is written in core of `module.exports` and for second case, you are using property of object